# How do I prevent data from our Teams account from showing up on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-for-teams

I have a free Teams Stack Overflow account (/c/spintype) but how do I prevent questions from the Teams from showing up on the main page?

There is for example, "spintype Recently Active Questions" which is really annoying, but I haven't found any way to remove it.

Update:

And just to clarify: The problem is "just" that my main Stack Overflow page looks different, due to the /c/spintype team plate.

The main problem and what really annoys me is that this also changes the "normal" view of my Stack Overflow page.

Even if I ignore "spintype Recently Active Questions", the main problem is that all the normal Stack Overflow questions are now placed inside another box called "Stack Overflow Recently Active Questions". This is really ugly because now the entire Stack Overflow question list is now in a box within a box. This is really what is my problem. Not so much the merge in of content from my /c/spintype but the fact that it changed my main Stack Overflow interface.

And I also no longer have access to the normal toolbar called "Newest","Active","Bountied","Unanswered","more".

[image]

Comment: You mean on the home page: https://stackoverflow.com/ ? You can collapse the container. It remembers your choice.

Comment: Yes, but even collapsed it is still annoying.

Comment: It is a feature. You can't prevent it from showing up there.

Comment: Custom user script, or just ads block the div.

Comment: If you have a team, why would you want to hide the teams from everywhere? You wouldn't know when someone asks an important question unless you actually check it. If you still want to hide it, just use uBlock to hide the div.

Comment: @10Rep On the front page it can be obtrusive. I can understand why they're making the request

Comment: folks, please, let's stop dismissing requests on the basis "just use the userscript / adblocker"! I am seeing this constantly. If the site was run by a non-profit or even by the community itself based on donations, I would understand that, but SE is a profit-driven company that uses free work of others - shall not the contributors expect their concerns, however small be at least *considered*? And it is far easier for the company to dismiss these concerns if *we* dismiss them in the first place.

Comment: I agree with Oleg. I don't use Teams but since other users explained how this isn't natively supported, I would turn this post into a feature request (by rewording it and using the appropriate tag).

Comment: Is your issue here *only* that your Team's questions are displayed *to you* on the main Stack Overflow "Recently Active Questions" page and/or other pages, or is it that you are concerned that your Team's data is leaking to other people on Stack Overflow who are not in your Team? Basically, your title and first sentence could be describing either, but your example tends to indicate the problem you have is what is displayed to you, rather than a leak of information. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @Makyen - trying to read minds a bit here: seems like the question is about persisting the preference of the "all"/"public"/"<team name>" dropdown as it resets itself to "all" every time one opens the "questions" tab or the homepage. That doesn't mean the OP should not clarify, just guessing

Comment: @10Rep See the update. The main problem is that the entire stackoverflow front page looks total different and ugly now. And that is not something I can fix with a css edit, because the html is different.

Comment: Just visit [/questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) also reachable from the left menu, right under Stack Overflow.

Comment: /questions gives quite a different list of results

Comment: @rene what if the OP wants to set a custom filter or watch a tag? The main page shows questions that you are likely more interested in, but /questions shows literally every question, 99 percent of which nobody wants to likely answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you join/create a Team, there is no way to hide it from the https://stackoverflow.com/ homepage. The only workaround is to navigate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions.

Comment: "The only workaround" - not technically true. https://ublockorigin.com/ - `##.mixed-question-list` should work